# Edit system variables using setx

Tags: environment-variables

I can't seem to find the right parameters of setx to modify an existing system environment variable. Basically, I have a variable that I want to append ".old" to.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the command that you have actually tried.

Comment: There was no parameters setx have for modifying variables.

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I append to an existing system environment variable using `setx`

Just add the extra data to the end of the variable.

**Example**:

```
> set _variable=foo

> echo %_variable%
foo

> setx _variable %_variable%bar

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

> echo %_variable%
foo
```

Note that is appears that the `setx` hasn't worked. This is because you must start a new `cmd` shell to see the change:

> `setx` writes variables to the master environment in the registry, edits will only take effect when a new command window is opened - they do not affect the current CMD or PowerShell session.

Source - [setx](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html)

Open a new `cmd` shell to see the change:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

> echo %_variable%
foobar
```

And we can see the correct value.

---

#### But I want to change the variable name. How do I do that?

You can't change the variable name directly as it is stored as a key value in the registry.

- As a workaround, create a new variable with the new name, and then delete the old one.
- `setx` doesn't have a delete option, so delete the variable from the registry.

**Example**:

```
setx _variable.old %_variable%
reg delete HKCU\Environment /F /V _variable
```

Open a new `cmd` shell to see the changes.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [reg](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) - Read, Set or Delete registry keys and values, save and restore from a .REG file.
- [setx](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) - Set environment variables permanently, SETX can be used to set Environment Variables for the machine (HKLM) or currently logged on user (HKCU).

Comment: It changes the value, not the variable name.

Comment: @Dumont Answer updated